# NFS mounted as readonly, why?

Tags: mount, nfs

I have an NFS share that I export myself and then want to mount as readwrite. But for some reason it's mounted as readonly.

```
$ mount | grep test
127.0.0.1:/var/sharepath on /test type nfs4    (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=127.0.0.1,local_lock=none,addr=127.0.0.1)


$ cat /etc/exports | grep sharepath
/var/sharepath *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Until here it looks good. right?

However: `touch: cannot touch ‘/test/asdf’: Read-only file system`

What might be the reason?

PS: var itself is also read write:

```
$ mount | grep lvol0
/dev/mapper/vg01r5-lvol0 on /var type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Comment: The "rw" in our output means it's mounted (and exported) as read-write.  What makes you think that it's mounted read only?

Comment: @L.Ray I added some error output from a simple example.

Comment: `/test/<name>` will cause it to try from root directory, try from `./test/asdf`or `/var/sharepath/test/asdf`(unless it's a spelling mistake, we all make those)

Comment: `/test` is a directory in root. That's correct. It is not `~/test` or something.

Comment: and `/var/sharepath` is for testing mounted to `/test`

Comment: What are the permissions for `/test`? `ls -l /test`

Comment: @NasirRiley it's 755, but I also can't change it when mounted. Before mounting it's 777.

Comment: Do not use `mount`, use `/proc/mounts` instead. Is `/var/sharepath` on the `/var` filesystem or is it a separate mount point?

Comment: @HaukeLaging What do you mean? What's the difference? And will it give you more debugging infos? Because if you find another way to make it work that doesn't give us feedback then all we found out is that my simplified example was too simplified. mounting something to `/test` is not the final solution of course, but just an example to show the problem.

Comment: You're both exporting and mounting the NFS share on the same system, is that correct?  What is the output of  `showmount -e 127.0.0.1`?  What if you used your public IP address instead of your loopback (127.0.0.1)  IP?

Comment: `mount` shows you the content of `/etc/mtab` which is not necessarily correct. `/proc/mounts` contains the kernel's current opinion about what is going on.

Comment: I see thanks. Btw for the problem at hand we could find the cause. Embarrasing copy&paste error as it seems. Interestingly `showmount -e 127.0.0.1` lists a lot of directories but no options (each line ends with a star). And interesting to see the difference between both outputs for proc and mtab.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this problem can have multiple sources. In our case it was really tricky.

In `/etc/exports` there was also a line that only said `/var` without any options etc. And that took precedence over `/var/sharepath` with all its options. After deleting that `/var` line it works. Probably a copy&paste error.

Another solution to similar problems might be [setting priorities](https://serverfault.com/questions/532760/why-is-an-nfs-server-mounted-as-rw-returning-read-only-filesystem-errors/641361#641361) via export configuration.